# Unable to Stop Android location updates after activity gets destroyed by configuration change

Tags: android

I am building an application that uses plays services API to get the location. I start the location updates with the next command:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

To stop it, I just execute the next piece of code which is executed when a "STOP" button is pressed:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Nevertheless if the configuration changes (for example, rotating the screen). When I press the button, the application goes to an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

Can you tell me, how can I stop the location updates with my "Stop" button after the screen has been rotated? 
Thanks a lot!

I dont want to DISABLE the configuration change when the screen gets rotated.

Comment: the requestLocationUpdates is inside your onCreate method?

Comment: @galvan OnCreate I initialize the  mGoogleAPIClient and start the location updates with this`code`  if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }else{
            createLocationRequest();
        }`code`

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you rotate a screen activity refresh itself. To handle this error try to use:

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

or just:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Comment: I am afraid the problem is that when the activity refreshes, the mGoogleAPIClient is lost and I cannot refer to that instance anymore to stop the location updates

Answer (score 0):

stop and restart the updating in the onPause() and onResume() methods, like the developer guide recommends:  http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html